# Tesseract: OCR hex and binary strings from old documents

Tags: ocr, image-processing, hexadecimal, tesseract-ocr

I have some questions about Tesseract

### Context

I am currently working on an old cryptographic algorithm from East Germany (GDR) which was developed in the 80s. I implemented the algorithm in C#. Now I have about 30 pages of test cases which I want to check. Because I don't want to manually type every binary/hex string I would like to OCR it with Tesseract (or any free software that works).

### Problem

I have problems getting satisfying results. Explained in more detail below.

### Current Status

(sorry, I can't directly post images) The document looks like this:
[part of a page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkUqC.png) / [letters in detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN1he.png)

### Naive Approach

With default settings (I use German shouldn't matter for the relevant parts) I get miserable results.

```bsh
tesseract -l deu input.tiff output pdf
```

The result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xeuh.png)
Especially the zeros cause trouble. Words, Letters and ones are recognised a little bit better.

### What I tried (preprocessing)

1. Rotate the page
2. Increase contrast
3. Binarize the image
4. Erode/Dilate the image to fill little gaps in between the letters

The final result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlmA0.png). As far is I know about OCR this should make things a little bit  better.

### What I tried (Tesseract settings)

My config file looks like the following:

```
load_system_dawg F
load_freq_dawg F
language_model_penalty_non_dict_word 0
language_model_penalty_non_freq_dict_word 0
tessedit_create_pdf T
tessedit_char_whitelist 0123456789ABCDEF
```

I basically tell Tesseract to not try to make useful words out of the letters and only allow characters necessary for hex strings.

As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn72v.png) this leads to slightly better results, but not in all cases. Some zeros in the last line are detected significantly better. In between the F nothing of use happens.

Playing with the settings Neural Network vs Classical OCR (--oem 0/1) is a little bit of difference. The classical algorithm detects many 0 as 9 (never as 0), but much more consistently (but not good)

### Question

What could I further do to improve the results? I know I could train the neural net additionally, but for what I read this takes some effort which I would like to dodge (building Tesseract for yourself, get the ML stuff to work, make labelled test data etc.).

Anything else?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I ended up using the Google docs OCR functionality. It worked way better than anything I could achieve with Tesseract. However, I am not satisfied with this approach.